# How to Map files to the Memory in Java nio?

Tags: java, io, mapping, nio, memory-mapped-files

I have a text file which I downloaded from the internet. File is large, somewhat around 77MB and I need to map it into the memory so I can read it fast. Here is my code

```
public class MapRead {

    public MapRead()
    {
        try {
            File file = new File("E:/Amazon HashFile/Hash.txt");
            FileChannel c = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r").getChannel();

            MappedByteBuffer buffer = c.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,c.size()).load();

            System.out.println(buffer.isLoaded());
            System.out.println(buffer.capacity());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MapRead.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

No good, this generated the below output.

```
false
81022554
```

This is my first time trying this. I have no idea what went wrong, or what to do next, to read the file.

Comment: What happens if you start using the buffer? Also [`isLoaded()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#isLoaded()) seems to be almost completely useless as it is only a guess.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I do not know. Can you goide me please? how to read things using this?

Comment: `load()` is only a hint. Note that it doesn’t make any sense to “improve” reading by memory mapping and invoking `load()` at the same time. The advantage of memory mapping is that the operating system can load pages on demand. If you tell it to load everything in right after establishing the memory mapping it will take exactly the same time as a simple `read` into an ordinary `ByteBuffer`.